# Show default username

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

**Hello**. I use this code to show user's display name with a shortcode. When user is not logged in, it is empty, is there a way to show **'Visitor'** or any other text when user is not logged in.

```
function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $display_name = $user->display_name;
    return $user->display_name;
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

Comment: If it returns `null` (empty) then use the [null coalescing operator](https://3v4l.org/E5981): `return $user->display_name ?? 'Visitor'`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the display is name is blank or null and returing the value by using php ternary operator:

```
return $display_name ? $display_name : "Visitor";
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/), that function will return an `WP_User` object with the ID set to `0` is no one is logged in.

```php
function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($user->ID){
        return $user->display_name;
    }

    return "Visitor";
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked just as I wanted. Thanks.